# Swagger Example Post Body From Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui

Does anyone know if it's possible to create an example post body with pre-populated/default values from Java annotations? My goal is for users to have a working example when viewing a POST endpoint in Swagger UI. Ideally this working example is created from annotations in the code.

For Example on a model object property:

```
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "http://istock.com/my_cool_image")
    @JsonProperty("submitted-image-url")
    private String submittedImageUrl;
```

Would produce something like this in Swagger UI (note the example URL shows up in the Model Schema):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried that in the code?  That's exactly how it works.  The input model will use `example` values for the mock

Comment: @fehguy Yea I've tried almost this exact code. It always seems to populate the value of submitted-image-url to "string" instead of what I specify as the example value in the above ApiModelProperty annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The way it appears to be designed, you have to click on Example Value under Data Type for the request/Value textarea to be populated (at least in Swagger 1.5.9).